# How to use Power BI (DAX) to get Average of two dates

Tags: dax

Average date between two dates in Power BI using DAX not working.

Is there a way to solve this using DAX?
Average days between Registration Date and Start Date (For all user IDs the difference between Start Date minus Registration Date.
[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data? What you have tried so far?

Comment: Please check my edited formula

Answer (score 1):

I would use a measure that takes the difference between the two dates, divides it by 2 and then adds the result to the start date:

This measure returns The average of two dates:

```
DATEADD(
    LASTDATE([Start Date]),
    DATEDIFF(
        LASTDATE([Start Date]),
        LASTDATE([Registration Date]),
        DAY
    )/2,
    DAY
)
```

EDIT: Changed MAX to LASTDATE.

EDIT2:

This Measure returns the Average difference between the two dates:

```
AVERAGEX('Table', [Start Date] - [Registration Date])
```

Comment: @Alan K , Thank you for the Code example above. I get an error.. It says the Registration Date parameter is not the correct type.

Comment: Sorry for that, i edited the code and added an explanation

Comment: @ Alan, I tried your code but it does not return anything.   Avg # of Days = DATEADD(
    LASTDATE('Table1'[Date]),
    DATEDIFF(
        LASTDATE('Table1'[Date]),
        LASTDATE('Table2'[Date]),
        DAY
    )/2,
    DAY
)

Comment: How can I get the Avg # of days to show a digit instead of a whole date? It shows the Average as whole date but not in digits for example if the average is 5, 9 10, 20 and so on but not like 11/20/2021 12:00:00AM

Comment: Is the measure working now?
To show the measure as number, use:

Date as Number = VALUE ([Date_Measure])

Comment: No. It's not working. I used the date as number but it shows as whole DATE like this for example 10/10/2020 12:00:00am etc even after using the calculation

Comment: Average # of Days  = DATEADD(LASTDATE('Table1'[Registration Date]), DATEDIFF(LASTDATE( 'Table1'[Registration Date]),LASTDATE('Table2'[Start Date] ),DAY)/2,DAY)

Comment: OK Try wrapping the measure:
Average # of Days = VALUE(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Table1'[Registration Date]), DATEDIFF(LASTDATE( 'Table1'[Registration Date]),LASTDATE('Table2'[Start Date] ),DAY)/2,DAY))

If it doesn't work then try to wrap it in the FORMAT Measure:
Average # of Days = FORMAT(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Table1'[Registration Date]), DATEDIFF(LASTDATE( 'Table1'[Registration Date]),LASTDATE('Table2'[Start Date] ),DAY)/2,DAY),"0")

Comment: VALUE did not work but FORMAT result was a weird number for two dates such as 45555 instead of few days like 15 or 20 when I looked at the two dates in that range

Comment: I might have misunderstood your intention, you seem to look for the average difference between two dates. Please check my Edit2.

Comment: The Edit2 provides a DATEDIFF but it's not an average.

Comment: Duration = DATEDIFF(Table1'[Registration Date], RELATED(‘Table2’[Start Date]), DAY)

Average # of Days  = AVERAGEX('Table1'[Registration Date]) - RELATED('Table2'[Start Date ])   both provide the same result.

Comment: Start Date: 3/1/2021, Registration Date: 2/1/2021  Duration = 28, Avg # of Days = 28

Comment: Anyone here to solve this?

Comment: Any experts here to help?

Comment: @Alex -- Your code returns the Average as total in the table but not for every row.

Comment: For all user id's the difference between the start date minus the registration date?
Lets say you have user id1, user id2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your title suggests you want to average dates but your comments on Alan's answer suggest that you want an average of durations between dates.

Supposing you have a table `Users` with one row per user, you could define the average number of days between registration and start as follows:

```
AVERAGEX (
    Users,
    DATEDIFF ( Users[Start Date], Users[End Date], DAY )
)
```

If you don't have such a table with one user per row, then you have to do a bit of extra work.

Comment: I want the Average days between Registration Date and Start Date. The Start Date column is in one table and the Registration date column is in another table. How would you get the average days between the two dates for every row in the table?

Comment: @POWERBI_SQL I can't say without knowing how the tables are structured and related but the same concept should still apply. Iterate over distinct users taking the date diff between start date and end date, however those are dates are determined.

Comment: @ Alexis, Can you provide an example with two tables? I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about you edit your post to include a toy example of a couple of tables? I don't think it makes sense for me to invent some since I'd have to guess at the structure.