# Power BI Drop Down selection does not affect Cards

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power Bi Dropdown does not affect the card values. I have 4 cards and based on the drop-down selection I want all the cards to get populated but it does not affect all of them. If I chose a value from the drop-down then it should display the count in the given card and update the rest for example if one card value is 40 and another is 30 and it should reflect the change based on the selected value in the drop-down but the cards have no affect. Any ideas?

Below are the 4 measures for the cards based on dropdown value selection.

The drop-down contains the following.

"Role Addition / Test"

"role removed / Test"

"Role Change"

4 cards are below:

RoleAdded = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), SEARCH("Role Addition", 'Table'[Column],,0)>0)

RoleRemoved = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), SEARCH("role removed", 'Table'[Column],,0)>0)

RoleChange = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),'Table'[Column] = "Role Change")

Total Changes = [RoleAdded] + [RoleChange] + [RoleRemoved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting your measures like this:

```
RoleAdded =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 'Table', CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Table'[Column], "Role Addition" ) )
)

RoleRemoved =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 'Table', CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Table'[Column], "role removed" ) )
)

RoleChange =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Column] = "Role Change" ) )
)

Total Changes = [RoleAdded] + [RoleChange] + [RoleRemoved]
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the solution. It works but when some cards have no values depending on other card selection the card shows the text blank. How can I display zero if there are no values to be counted?

Comment: Also selecting multiple value from the drop-down does not add up the numbers in the card?

Comment: You can add `+ 0 ` to each expression to return zero instead of blank. I'm not sure what you mean about does "not add up".

Comment: Adding the 0 worked. Thank you so much. It really helped a lot. I accept this solution.

Comment: @Alex-- Can you help with this question I posted as separate question. No one is able to solve this. How to use Power BI (DAX) to get Average of two dates?

Comment: There's a button to accept an answer. :)

Comment: Here is the link for that question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307186/how-to-use-power-bi-dax-to-get-average-of-two-dates?noredirect=1#comment124327820_70307186